# onkeyup not working

Tags: jquery

my expected output is

As i type on input text field i get instant sum on third text field

if i type 3 on first text field and key is up , instantly 3+0=3 have to show on  third field

but doesnt show any result

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var a=0, b=0,c=0;

        $("input:#a").keyup(function(){
            a=$("input:#a").val();
            c=a+b;
            $("input:#c").append(a+"+"+"b"+"="+c);
         });

        $("input:#a").keyup(function(){
            b=$("input:#b").val();
            c=a+b;
            $("input:#c").append(a+"+"+b+"="+c);
        });

     });



        <tr><td><input type="text" id="a"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="b"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="c"></td></tr>
```

Comment: You have three different forms of selectors (`input:#a`, `#input a` and `input #a`), none of them correct. That's quite a feat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something along the lines of the following:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A<input type="text" id="a" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>B<input type="text" id="b" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>C<input type="text" id="c" /></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- If you need this: -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=0, 
        b=0;

    $('input#a').bind('keyup', function(e){
        a = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        var c = (a + b);

        $('input#c').val(a + '+' + b + '=' + c);
    });  

    $('input#b').bind('keyup', function(e){
        b = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        var c = (a + b);

        $('input#c').val(a + '+' + b + '=' + c);
    });

});
```

This code performs the calculation and puts the result in box C, and automatically updates C with the result of the calculation.

Comment: Thankyou! your code fixed the problem. i get NaN while text field is empty. what does that mean? is there a way to set NaN to 0?

Comment: It means 'Not a Number'. I'll updated the answer to account for this :)

Comment: Alright, give that a try now, it should say 0 instead of NaN for anything other than integers.

Comment: Tried it,it shows 0. whats the significance of e inside function(e), i removed function(e) to function() still code works fine.why e is used?

Comment: I guess that's a habit haha, event functions in jQuery like this, or for example click event functions etc get passed an event object, the `e` in this case is the event object. In this instance it isn't necessary as it's not used, but it can do some very handy stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating strings.  You need to actually add the numbers (and not use `.append`):

```
$("#c").text(parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
```

Additionally, you should write as `).on('keyup', function () {` rather than `).onkeyup`

Comment: There are quite a lot of other problems there as well. Also, I think the OP wants the field to show "2+3=5", not just the result. Also also, `#c` is an input field so `.text()` won't work.

Comment: It is a good idea to use `parseInt` with the base parameter like `parseInt(a,10)`. Because `parseInt("08")` returns `0` instead of `8`

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is `.keyup()` instead `.onkeyup`.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: @violetkiwi the u in up is in lowercase... Javascript is very b!tchy when it comes to upper and lowercase functions.. also you might want to use the method above aswell for the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = 0,
        b = 0;
    $("input#a").on('keyup', function () {
        a = parseInt($("input#a").val());
        $("input#c").val(parseInt(a + b););
    });

    $("input#a").on('keyup', function () {
        b = parseInt($("input#b").val());
        $("input#c").val(parseInt(a + b););
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't actually calculate anything